# How to access a variable in another function?

Tags: angular, typescript, datasource

I have a variable 'temp', which consists of an array of Transactions. 
In `ngOnInit()` I subscribe to a service, which sends transactions to the `MinerViewComponent`. This transactions then get displayed in a table in the `MinerViewComponent`. 
'temp' consists of all the transactions. 
When I click on a button the function `sendBlockToBC()` gets called. 
What I expected was the array with the transactions, but all I get is '[]'. The console.log in the `ngOnInit()` works fine. I get all the transactions in an array.

I tried to create another variable, because I thought, that `this.temp.pop()` would be the problem, but it still gives me an empty array.

```
export interface Transaction {
  sender: number;
  recipient: number;
  amount: number;
  fee: number;
}

const ELEMENT_DATA: Transaction[] = [
];

@Component({
  selector: 'app-miner-view',
  templateUrl: './miner-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./miner-view.component.css']
})
export class MinerViewComponent implements OnInit {
  transaction: Transaction;
  displayedColumns: string[] = ['sender', 'recipient', 'amount', 'fee'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Transaction>(ELEMENT_DATA);
  temp: Transaction[] = [];
  blockNumber = 0;
  previousHash = '00000000000000000000000000000000';
  blockHash: string = this.generateBlockHash();

  constructor(private _TS: TransactionPoolToMinerService, private ref: ChangeDetectorRef) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this._TS.transaction$.subscribe(transaction => {
        this.transaction = transaction;
        this.temp = this.dataSource.data.slice();
        this.temp.push(this.transaction);
        this.dataSource.data = this.temp;

        //console.log(this.temp);

        this.ref.detectChanges();
      }
    );
    this.temp = this.dataSource.data.slice();
    this.temp.pop();
    this.dataSource.data = this.temp;
    this.ref.detectChanges();
  }

  sendBlockToBC() {

    //console.log(this.temp);

    let block = new Block(this.blockNumber, this.temp, this.previousHash, this.blockHash);
    this.raiseBlockNumber();
    this.generateBlockHash();
  }


  raiseBlockNumber() {
    this.blockNumber++;
  }

  /** This method creates a random string of the alphabet [a-z0-9] to demonstrate a block hash out of 32 digits **/
  generateBlockHash() {    
}
```

I think I found the problem. I tried calling `console.log(this.temp)` in the `MinerViewComponent`for the function `sendBlockToBC()`. This gave me the right array.

But the button gets called in another component:

HTML:

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary">
  <span>Blockchain Simulation</span>
  <span class="fill-remaining-space"></span>
  <button mat-button (click)=triggerServiceMVToBC()>Mine</button>
</mat-toolbar>
```

TS:

```
@Component({
  providers: [MinerViewComponent],
  selector: 'app-toolbar',
  templateUrl: './toolbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./toolbar.component.css']
})
export class ToolbarComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private minerViewComponent: MinerViewComponent) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  triggerServiceMVToBC() {
    this.minerViewComponent.sendBlockToBC();
  }

}
```

I got a toolbar, where the button is. The toolbar is an own component. When clicking on the button I call the function `sendBlockToBC()` for the `MinerViewComponent`. The problem probably is the constructor, which creates a new `MinerViewComponent`. What is an elegant way to solve that problem?

Comment: How did you create another variable?

Comment: is the toolbarComponent initialized inside your MinerViewComponent or would you also paste your MinerViewComponent template ?

Comment: I updated the post.